# Whats the best way to implement a database with multivalued attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am trying to implement a database which has multi valued attributes and create a filter based search. For example i want my people_table to contain id, name, address, hobbies, interests (hobbies and interests are multi-valued). The user will be able to check many attributes and sql will return only those who have all of them.

I made my study and i found some ways to implement this but i can't decide which one is the best.

1. The first one is to have one table with the basic info of people (id, name, address), two more for the multi-valued attributes and one more which contains only the keys of the other tables (i understand how to create this tables, i don't know yet how to implement the search).
2. The second one is to have one table with the basic info and then one for each attribute. So i will have 20 or more tables (football, paint, golf, music,  hiking etc.) which they only contain the ids of the people. Then when the user checks the hobbies and the activities i am going to get the desired results with the use of the JOIN feature (i am not sure about the complexity, so i don't know how fast is going to be if the user do many checks).
3. The last one is an implementation that i didn't find on internet (and i know there is a reason :) ) but in my mind is the easiest to implement and the fastest in terms of complexity. Use only one table which will have the basic infos as normal and also all the attributes as boolean variables. So if i have 1000 people in my table there are going to be only 1000 loops and which i imagine with the use of AND condition are going to be fast enough.

So my question is: can i use the the third implementation or there is a big disadvantage that i don't get? And also which one of the first two ways do you suggest me to use?

Comment: How much detail are you tracking about these hobbies?

Comment: Option 2 sounds horrendous, and option 3 sounds bad and unnormalized.  The first option is the way to go IMO, and you can check out the @Juergen answer below for more information.

Comment: thank you all for the quick responses. @Schewrn i need about 50 hobbies and  interests (just the names).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   the first option is better than the third no matter how many rows i have?

Comment: The third option might run faster in certain cases because there would be no (or less) joining, but it is bad design and doesn't scale well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks a lot you have been very helpful.

Comment: "*if i have 1000 people in my table there are going to be only 1000 loops*" Hold it. Don't think of the efficiency of SQL queries in terms of "loops". With good indexes, and good table design, SQL will rarely have to search through all the data (known as a "full table scan").

Comment: thanks a lot @Schwern, i was just thinking that the third option has complexity of N but meanwhile the first one has 2*N because it will search in both tables. I suppose i  must think of a sorting to make my searches faster or study better :)

Comment: @BroCode As long as you properly declare the foreign keys (ie. `references table(id)`) they will automatically be indexed and simple joins like the ones in juergen's answer will be very fast no matter how big the tables get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a typical **n to m relation**. It works like this

```
persons table
------------
id
name
address

interests table
---------------
id
name

person_interests table
----------------------
person_id
interest_id
```

`person_interests` contains a record for each interest of a person. To get the interests of a person do:

```
select i.name
from interests i
join person_interests pi on pi.interest_id = i.id
join persons p on pi.person_id = p.id
where p.name = 'peter'
```

You could create also tables for `hobbies`. To get the hobbies do the same in a separate query. To get both in one query you can do something like this

```
select p.id, p.name, 
       i.name as interest, 
       h.name as hobby
from persons p    
left join person_interests pi on pi.person_id = p.id
left join interests i on pi.interest_id = i.id
left join person_hobbies ph on ph.person_id = p.id
left join hobbies h on ph.hobby_id = h.id
where p.name = 'peter'
```

Comment: could i create also a table for hobbies or then i couldn't make use of the JOIN feature?

Comment: @BroCode I'd ask yourself if there's really a difference between a "hobby" and an "interest".

Comment: @BroCode: Yes, of course you can create also a `hobbies` table.

Comment: yeah i know, you are right but i actually need two other tables (facilities and characteristics). I just use these two to keep it simple. :)

Comment: @BroCode: That is not a problem. Create those tables for all the relations you have. This is how you map a n-to-m relation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to deal with this is with a many-to-many join table. Each user can have many hobbies. Each hobby can have many users. That's basic stuff you can find information about anywhere, and [@juergend already covered that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221189/14660).

The harder part is tracking different information about various hobbies and interests. Like if their hobby is "baseball" you might want to track what position they play, but if their hobby is "travel" you might want to track their favorite countries. Doing this with typical SQL relationships will lead to a rapid proliferation of tables and columns.

A hybrid approach is to use the new [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) to store *some* unstructured data. To expand on @juergend's example, you might add a field to Person_Interests which can store some of those details about that person's interest.

```
create table Person_Interests (
    InterestID integer references Interests(ID),
    PersonID integer references Persons(ID),
    Details JSON
);
```

And now you could add that Person 45 has Interest 12 (travel), their favorite country is Djibouti, and they've been to 45 countries.

```
insert into person_interests
    (InterestID, PersonID, Details)
    (12, 45, '{"favorite_country": "Djibouti", "countries_visited": 45}');
```

And you can use JSON search functions to find, for example, everyone whose favorite country is Djibouti.

```
select p.id, p.name
from person_interests pi
join persons p on p.id = pi.personid
where pi.details->"$.favorite_country" = "Djibouti"
```

The advantage here is flexibility: interests and their attributes aren't limited by your database schema.

The disadvantages is performance. The JSON data type isn't the most efficient, and [indexing a JSON column in MySQL is complicated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index). Good indexing is critical to good SQL performance. So as you figure out common patterns you might want to turn commonly used attributes into real columns in real tables.

---

The other option would be to use [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-inherit.html). This is a feature of Postgres, not MySQL, and I'd recommend considering switching. Postgres also has [better and more mature JSON support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) and [JSON columns are easier to index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html).

With table inheritance, rather than having to write a completely new table for every different interest, you can make specific tables which inherit from a more generic one.

```
create table person_interests_travel (
    FavoriteCountry text,
    CountriesVisited text[]
) inherits(person_interests);
```

This still has InterestID, PersonID, and Details, but it's added some specific columns for tracking their favorite country and countries they've visited.

Note that `text[]`. [Postgresql also supports arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html) so you can store real lists without having to create another join table. You can also do this in MySQL with a JSON field, but arrays offer type constraints that JSON does not.